# Can we increase the `Short text, list field` limit in Contentful?

Tags: contentful, contentful-management, contentful-api

I am using Contentful to fetch some data for my website.

I have a productId field in Contentful for each entry which is of type `Short text, list field`. This field accepts product ids as comma-separated values.

`ID1234,ID2343, ID2344, .......`

But this seems to be limited to `1000` IDs.

Is there a way by which I can add up to 100k IDs? By using some other types than using `Short text, list field` or by upgrading the Contentful account.

Answer (score 1):

Contentful DevRel here.

I think this is a hard limit on all pricing tiers.

What you could do is to use the `JSON` field instead. If the editors are not tech-savvy JSON is obviously not the best choice. In that case you could use [the App Framework](https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/extensibility/app-framework/) and put some custom UI on top of the JSON field.